# Regex Pattern not working

Tags: validation-rule, regular-expressions

I not want the user to add the symbols in the opportunity column. I implemented the validation in the validator. But it is not working.

```
NOT(REGEX(Account_Name_CAD__c", "^[#$%^&*+=-_/><~`]+$"))
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help], scroll through the [tour], and read [ask]. What exactly is not working? Which inputs, that you expect it to prevent, did it not prevent? Feel free to [edit] your question with more specifics/details.

Answer (score 2):

Your formula includes a number of mistakes.

- You've written your regex to match the *entire string*, not *any character within the string*. `^` matches the string start, and `$` the string end.
- You've failed to escape special characters within the list of symbols. `-` has a meaning in a regex (it defines a character range). You must escape it with a backslash.
- You have a spurious `"` character in your formula, which will prevent the entire formula from compiling.

All that aside, I'm very skeptical of this approach in the first place. There are many, many symbols in Unicode that your regex won't notice at all. If you want your Opportunity names to have a specific format, be prescriptive about that format rather than attempting to block a set of characters.

Sites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) can help you test your regular expressions to make sure they do what you intend them to do.

---

Per your comment, your goal is to sanitize sObject data for inclusion as a URL parameter. You should *not* do this with a regex-based validation rule. Instead, you should be URL-encoding the data before including it in the URL, as with any user-controlled data you include in a URL.

Comment: I am sending the opportunity name in the URL. I do not want to break the URL. Could you please suggest the regrex pattern? @David Reed

Comment: That is the wrong approach. You should be URL-encoding the parameter value.